# Hold Map response from http response in Angular/typescript

Tags: angular

I have a service that returns a map of key values pairs `Map<String, List<String>>`

```
{
    "code1": [
        "F10",
        "F11"
    ],
    "code2": [
        "F12",
        "F13"
    ]
}
```

I am trying to hold this response in angular app

```
getCodes(): Observable<Map<string, string[]>> {
   return this.http.get<Map<string, string[]>>(url, {headers})
        .pipe(map((response: Map<string, string[]>) => {
          return response;
        }));
    }
```

and after I subcribe to the observable and try to access the map with key, I am getting an error `this.codes.get is not a function`

***Component:***

```
codes = new Map<string, string[]>();

this.service.getCodes().subscribe(response => {
 this.codes = response;
 console.log('for code1', this.codes.get('code1'));
}
```

when I log the response, it is not looking like a map. Pls help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting not a map, but a json.

You can type it correctly with:

```
return this.http.get<Record<string, string[]>>(url, {headers});
// note no "map(..)" is done. It is doing nothing so I omitted it
```

In order to convert it to `Map` you can use:

```
this.codes = new Map(Object.entries(response));
```

Comment: Thank you this helped